# how to hide and show a div if it is not hover or clicked after some time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a sticky navbar onScroll and if I stop scrolling and do not click on it or do not hover on it, the navbar will disappear. I add the sticky functionality of the navbar and it works fine. But I am not able to hide if when I am not scrolling and do not click on it or do not hover on it for five seconds.

Comment: what research have you done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scroll listener and timers to realize when a user stop scrolling:

```
let scrolling;
  window.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
      window.clearTimeout(scrolling); 
//this is to stop the timer when you scroll again
scrolling = window.setTimeout(doSomething(),5000);
//each time you scroll and stop the counter will start
 
    });

const doSomething = ()=>{
.
.
.
};
```

Comment: actually, there is another animation that causes auto-scrolling, I  tried your solution, but it is not working

Comment: What animation are you talking about? Can you share a piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

scrolling is different from clicking or hovering, I will tell you how to hide or show if it is not scrolling You can apply the same method by clicking or hovering but in this case you will use an integer that increments for each click or hover.

1- Defining a variable called previousScroll will assign it a value of `document.documentElement.scrollTop;` And this variable will help us to check if the user has changed the scroll position or not (scroll or not)

2- add scroll event listener when user scroll first thing we will clear previous timeout which we will set in next step also it will show navigation bar with style.display="block" or css class

3- The last thing will be set Timeout which will be called after 5 seconds to check if the previous scroll is equal to `document.documentElement.scrollTop;` or not if they are equal, so the user does not scroll for 5 seconds because if he scrolls then this value will change and if so we can hide the navbar, when he scrolls again it will appear and so on the code example.

```js
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".navbar");

let myVar;

function checkScroll() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ 
     if (document.documentElement.scrollTop == lastTop){
       navMenu.style.display = "none";
     }
  
  }, 5000);
}

function clearTimeoutFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}

let lastTop = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
  clearTimeout(myVar);
  navMenu.style.display = "block";
  lastTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  checkScroll();
});
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
```